# Maven MOJO dependency injection and parameters

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, plexus

When using Plexus for MOJO plugin DI, is there a way to inject MOJO configuration parameter (annotated with `@Parameter` in the Mojo class) in other components as well?

In other words: Is there a way I can share Mojo parameters with other Plexus components apart from injecting the Mojo itself in other components, or resorting to hand-rolled "init method"? I was kinda hoping parameters would be managed by DI context.

Let's say I have a Mojo like this:

```
@Mojo
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    @Parameter
    private String param;

    @Inject
    private SomeComponent component;
}
```

Then it would be nice to do something like this:

```
@Named
public class SomeComponent {
    @Inject // or whatever else
    private String param;

    // some methods that use param here
}
```

Instead of having to do:

```
@Mojo
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    @Parameter
    private String param;

    @Inject
    private SomeComponent component;

    @Override
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
        component.setParam(param);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `SomeComponent` can be used outside of the Maven plugin, since it's a (reusable) component. If it's that strongly related to your Mojo, maybe there's something wrong in the design and you shouldn't have it in the first place. Also, components are generally immutable and thread-safe; having a setter is not recommended.

Comment: What makes it strongly related to the mojo? The fact that it expects a string to be injected? It doesn't make it anymore coupled then a setter. Injecting it would be just a way to avoid boilerplate.

Comment: The fact that it expects a String to be injected, in the context of using it from a plugin. What would happen if the Mojo is used twice in the same build, with different values of `param`? `SomeComponent` is shared and it's the same instance that'll be injected (by default, but you can't really change it from the plugin side).

Comment: Ok, so the question remains: how do you externalize component's configuration?

Comment: That's the thing, `param` is not a configuration element of the component, since it changes while the component won't change. It shouldn't hold any state. You would pass that value as parameter, `myComponent.doTheFoo(param);` where that method does something, but doesn't mutate the component. Put another way, the plugin knows the component, but not the other way around.

Comment: How about project properties? These should have the same lifespan as the component, right? Would I be able to inject them?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can have a multi-module project, (and furthermore, built in parallel). It really sounds like your component should not exist, or isn't decoupled enough from the Mojo.